# NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData can not archive a NSObject (swift with Xcode 8)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

**1. Why get exception when running swift program in XCode8**

**2. Error message**

2016-09-17 21:59:56.370839 MyCalendar[1032:29793] subsystem: com.apple.UIKit, category: HIDEventFiltered, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 1, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
2016-09-17 21:59:56.371720 MyCalendar[1032:29793] subsystem: com.apple.UIKit, category: HIDEventIncoming, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 1, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
2016-09-17 21:59:56.390463 MyCalendar[1032:29782] subsystem: com.apple.BaseBoard, category: MachPort, enable_level: 1, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 0, privacy_setting: 0, enable_private_data: 0
2016-09-17 21:59:56.412030 MyCalendar[1032:29746] subsystem: com.apple.UIKit, category: StatusBar, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 1, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
2016-09-17 21:59:56.509619 MyCalendar[1032:29746] subsystem: com.apple.BackBoardServices.fence, category: App, enable_level: 1, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 0, privacy_setting: 0, enable_private_data: 0
2016-09-17 21:59:57.215510 MyCalendar[1032:29746] subsystem: com.apple.UIKit, category: Touch, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 1, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 1, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
2016-09-17 21:59:57.216554 MyCalendar[1032:29746] subsystem: com.apple.UIKit, category: Gesture, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 1, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 1, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
2016-09-17 21:59:57.218087 MyCalendar[1032:29746] subsystem: com.apple.UIKit, category: GestureEnvironment, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 1, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 1, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
2016-09-17 21:59:57.218933 MyCalendar[1032:29746] subsystem: com.apple.UIKit, category: GestureExclusion, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 1, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 1, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
2-5
2016-09-17 22:00:00.519 MyCalendar[1032:29746] -[MyCalendar.CalendarEvent encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x78e68120
2016-09-17 22:00:00.547 MyCalendar[1032:29746] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MyCalendar.CalendarEvent encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x78e68120'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00b95212 **exceptionPreprocess + 194
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0064de66 objc_exception_throw + 52
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00c0e3dc -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 172
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00b1434c ___forwarding_** + 1052
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00b13f0e _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
    5   Foundation                          0x001ef60a _encodeObject + 1304
    6   Foundation                          0x001ef0ea -[NSKeyedArchiver encodeObject:forKey:] + 193
    7   Foundation                          0x0022548a +[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:] + 172
    8   MyCalendar                          0x000d47d2 _TFC10MyCalendar28SingleDayTableViewController16addButtonPressedfT6senderCSo15UIBarButtonItem_T_ + 1042
    9   MyCalendar                          0x000d4dad _TToFC10MyCalendar28SingleDayTableViewController16addButtonPressedfT6senderCSo15UIBarButtonItem_T_ + 61
    10  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00663200 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 63
    11  UIKit                               0x00f9e81e -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 91
    12  UIKit                               0x01447f00 -[UIBarButtonItem(UIInternal) _sendAction:withEvent:] + 186
    13  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00663200 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 63
    14  UIKit                               0x00f9e81e -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 91
    15  UIKit                               0x00f9e7b8 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 41
    16  UIKit                               0x0114d32b -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 64
    17  UIKit                               0x0114d693 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 462
    18  UIKit                               0x0114d84a -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 901
    19  UIKit                               0x0114c518 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 717
    20  UIKit                               0x01014fac -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 3063
    21  UIKit                               0x010167e7 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 4312
    22  UIKit                               0x00fbd198 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 395
    23  UIKit                               0x018646cd **dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 3706
    24  UIKit                               0x0185c7af __handleEventQueue + 5345
    25  CoreFoundation                      0x00b34cbf __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 15
    26  CoreFoundation                      0x00b18df7 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 519
    27  CoreFoundation                      0x00b18284 __CFRunLoopRun + 1124
    28  CoreFoundation                      0x00b17bab CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 395
    29  CoreFoundation                      0x00b17a0b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    30  GraphicsServices                    0x04dd1b4c GSEventRunModal + 177
    31  GraphicsServices                    0x04dd19c7 GSEventRun + 80
    32  UIKit                               0x00f9c7fb UIApplicationMain + 148
    33  MyCalendar                          0x000d7431 main + 145
    34  libdyld.dylib                       0x03f69799 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

**3. Source code**

......

let ce = CalendarEvent(withTitle: newEvent, andDateString: defaultKey)

let encodedCE = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: ce)

......

//class CalendarEvent
import Foundation

class CalendarEvent : NSObject {
    var title : String
    var dateString : String

```
init(withTitle t : String, andDateString ds : String) {
    title = t
    dateString = ds
}

init(withCoder coder : NSCoder) {
    dateString = coder.decodeObject(forKey: "dateString") as! String
    title = coder.decodeObject(forKey: "title") as! String
}

func encodeWithCoder(coder : NSCoder) {
    coder.encode(dateString, forKey: "dateString")
    coder.encode(title, forKey: "title")
}
```

}

**4. Try with other object**

For withRootObject, while place a String (instead of CalendarEvents), everything works well.

Answer (score 0):

please refer the following

1. First open & edit the schema
2. Select Arguments tab
3. Add/Set OS_ACTIVITY_MODE = disable in environmental variable
4. Close and run

Check following reference for more details

https://twitter.com/rustyshelf/status/775505191160328194